# void function Math error

Tags: c++, function, math, void

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void compute_coins(int change, int quarters, int dimes, int nickels, int pennies);
void output(int quarters, int dimes, int nickels, int pennies);

int main()
{
  int change, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies;
  char again = 'y';

  cout << "Welcome to the change dispenser!\n";

  while(again == 'y'){//Creating loop to allow the user to repeat the process
    cout << "Please enter the amount of cents that you have given between 1 and 99\n";
    cin >> change;
    while((change < 0) || (change >100)){//Making a loop to make sure a valid number is             inputed
        cout << "Error: Sorry you have entered a invalid number, please try again:";
        cin >> change;
    }
    cout << change << " Cents can be given as: " << endl;
    compute_coins(change, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies);
    output(quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies);

    cout << "Would you like to enter more change into the change dispenser?  y/n\n";//prompts the user to repeat this process
    cin >> again;
  }
  return 0;
}


void compute_coins(int change, int quarters, int dimes, int nickels, int pennies) {//calculation to find out the amount of change given for the amount inpuied
    using namespace std;
    quarters = change / 25;
    change = change % 25;
    dimes = change / 10;
    change = change % 10;
    nickels = change / 5;
    change = change % 5;
    pennies = change;
    return ;
}

void output(int quarters, int dimes, int nickels, int pennies){
  using namespace std;
  cout << "Quarters = " << quarters << endl;
  cout << "dimes = " << dimes << endl;
  cout << "nickels = " << nickels << endl;
  cout << "pennies = " << pennies << endl;
}
```

Sorry the code didn't transfer well and I'm pretty new to this site still. But, I am getting crazy numbers for the outcome on the quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies. I did this once already and it worked fine but I didn't use void functions, so I had to redo it and I messed myself up and I'm stuck. any help appreciated!

Comment: C++ is pass-by-value unless you specify a reference.

Comment: What *specifically* is going wrong?  What *specifically* have you tried so far?  We'd love to help out, but without some guidance it's hard for us to answer your question.  Can you update your question with some more details?

Comment: Your compiler is capable of giving useful warnings if you let it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6449ef3601fb9ef4

Answer (score 0):

```
void compute_coins(int change, int quarters, int dimes, int nickels, int pennies);
```

This means that you only take in a copy of the values you pass to the function. Hence whatever you do within the function won`t have any effect on the actual values that you pass in.

```
void compute_coins(int &change, int &quarters, int &dimes, int &nickels, int &pennies);
```

This means that you give the actual variables, not just a copy. Whatever changes you do on the parameters is actually done on the variables that you pass in.

**Look up refences and pointers.**